# Storing API key securely for pure JS script for website

Tags: javascript, secret-key

I am building a website for some friends and myself. For this, I am fetching data from an API to display on the website. I have just built an HTML + CSS page and added a pure JS script and uploaded all three files to my file manager on my domain. The script runs every time the page is opened, and I add the script to fetch data like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Since what I'm building is very lightweight, how can I securely store the API key in the simplest way possible instead of having it hardcoded in my script?

I've tried placing a `secret.js` file in the root folder of my domain (one folder higher, outside the actual domain that will be accessed), but I am unable to read the API key from there, and I get this error in the console:

`GET http://<my-domain>.com/secret.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Despite trying to access it outside the domain folder with this statement in my HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../secret.js"></script>`

A solution similar to this would be preferred. I would like to avoid any third-party tools, packages, etc.

Comment: If the API key is needed for client code, there's nothing you can do to hide it.